# How to animate resizing of a UIView which uses a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

**Intention:**

I want to draw a circle within a view that I can move, resize and re-colour from the ViewController.

**Setup:**

I subclassed UIView to create a view to just hold the circle:

```
@implementation CircleView

+ (Class)layerClass //override
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.opaque = NO;
        CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
        layer.fillColor = nil;
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1].CGColor;
        layer.lineWidth = 2;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
    layer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
}

@end
```

I then initialise it like so in the parent view initWithFrame:

```
{
    CGFloat diam = MIN(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    self.circleView = [[VCCCircleView alloc] initWithFrame:ASRectCenteredOnPoint(ASRectGetCenter(frame), (CGSize){diam,diam})];
    self.circleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [self addSubview:self.circleView];
}
```

Finally the parent view also provides a method for animating the view:

```
-(void)setCircleFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.circleView.layer;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:10 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^(void)
    {
        circleView.frame = frame;
//for debug:        circleView.frame = CGRectInset(circleView.frame, -30, -30);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

The idea being that you can just set the frame and the circle will move and resize. Simple right?

**Problem:**

The circle does *not*animate it's change in size but it does animate it's change in position. - the result being it jumps to the new size, then animates the movement of the origin. This is particularly obvious with the large delay I introduced to the animation.

I notice that if i just change the location of the circle, layoutSubviews of the circleView is not called  but if I change the bounds it is.

I am not using any transform.

**What I've tried:**

- Removing the autoresizemask stuff from the initialisation of the circle view
- Various combinations of options to the animation (including: `BeginFromCurrentState`)
- Calling [self layoutSubviews] in the animation block after the new frame is set
- Editing the bounds rather than the frame
- Combinations of the above

**What I haven't tried:**

- Using a CABasicAnimation directly. Is this necessary? 'Frame' is
  supposed to be animatable of UIView?

Comment: Did you try animating `center` for moving and `bounds` for resizing?

Comment: ah yes i tried that too, will add to my 'tried' list. thanks

Comment: The solution was to `CABasicAnimation` directly inside a `CATransaction` - set the frame of the layer to the new frame and then set the value of the `CABasicAnimation` to the new `CGPath`. In the completion block of the `CATransation`, set the path to the layer itself.

Comment: any solution other than using CABasicAnimation?

Comment: not that i could find. i think it's a bug or there is some property that is animatable related to the bounds